# SHA hashes same string into different blobs

Tags: java, passwords, sha

I am using the following code to hash an incoming string, in expecting that same thing applied to the method multiple times will always get the same results. The scenario will be for password hashing and later verification. But it doesn't seem to work - I got two different blobs for the same input string. Is there anything wrong or missing with my code?

```
public synchronized String encrypt(String token) {
    try {
        MessageDigest sha = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA");
        sha.reset();
        sha.update(token.getBytes("UTF-8"));
        byte[] raw = sha.digest();
        System.out.println("raw = " + raw.toString());
        String hash = Base64.encodeBase64(raw).toString();
        return hash;
    } catch (Exception e) {
    }

    return token;
}
```

Comment: Add the tag of the relevant languages. I believe that you've forgotten to add `Java`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You haven't really given enough information, but I suspect you're being distracted by this:

```
System.out.println("raw = " + raw.toString());
```

That's going to print out something like `[B@30a4effe` which has *nothing* to do with the data in the byte array. You should print out `hash` instead - which *should* be the same for all calls, if your `token` is genuinely the same.

(As noted by Dan, your method is inappropriately named: hashing isn't encryption. Also, please don't catch `Exception` *or* just swallow exceptions like this. It seems pretty odd to just return `token` on failure, too.)

EDIT: As noted, I've assumed that `Base64.encode` actually returns a String, which it may not. I'd recommend [this base64 implementation](http://iharder.sourceforge.net/current/java/base64/) which is public domain and has a sensible API - the encoding calls return a String, which is entirely appropriate. Of course, you then don't need the explicit `toString()` call as well...

Comment: Thanks for the catches! What are the additional steps needed for a real encryption? My code was written following some sample code that said to do password encryption.

Comment: @tom: For passwords, you probably *shouldn't* be using reversible encryption. Even hashing isn't good on its own - you should at least salt the hash, as well as picking an appropriate hashing algorithm. (Do a search for salt hash cryptography for more details.)

Comment: This doesnt actually solve his problem though. He is calling `toString` on a byte array and returning that as his final result. That's why the results are random every time.

Comment: @Perception: It depends on what `Base64.encodeBase64(raw)` returns - there are lots of Base64 classes around.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what Base64 class you are using, but I will assume the one from Apache Commons. You are doing this:

```
String hash = Base64.encodeBase64(raw).toString();
```

Which is calling the `toString` method on whatever random byte array is returned from the `Base64.encodeBase64()` method. That is why your result is random every time, you are just returning an object reference as a String. Try this instead:

```
String hash = Base64.encodeBase64String(raw);
```

**EDIT**

As pointed out in another post, converting directly to String is probably a bad idea. I edited my answer slightly to reflect that.